# How to inject services in directives testing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive which has a dependency on one of the services. It has a method called getcustomers(). While I am trying to test the directive How do I inject that service?

Comment: Add addition to @howderek commit, I would like to add link to plunker snippet for testing using AngularJS and Jasmine: http://plnkr.co/edit/gist:3743008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  var app = angular.module('mymod', []);
        app.service('myser', myservicename);
        app.directive('mydir', mydir);

//Before Beforeeach(inject) 
beforeEach(module('mymod'));  //This loads all the necessary dependencies for your directive


spyOn(myservice, 'methodname').andCallThrough();

That's it..above line mocks the service call and lets you call it....
```